# How to remove Nothing from an array eltype when there are no nothing in the array?

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, julia

For instance, if the output of a function (e.g. `indexin`) has the `Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}` type,
but it is known in advance that only values will be output (no `nothing`).
And this output should be fed to another function
which is buggy for such a type, but fine with an array of simple `Int64`.

Say

```
julia> output = Union{Nothing, Int64}[1, 2]  # in practice, that would be output from a function
2-element Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}:
 1
 2
```

How to convert that output to an array of `Int64` ?

The following works in this case, and could be gathered in a function, but there must be a more elegant way.

```
julia> subtypes = Base.uniontypes(eltype(output))
2-element Vector{Any}:
 Nothing
 Int64

julia> no_Nothing = filter(!=(Nothing), subtypes)
1-element Vector{Any}:
 Int64

julia> new_eltype = Union{no_Nothing...}
Int64

julia> Array{new_eltype}(output)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `something`:

```
julia> output = Union{Nothing, Int64}[1, 2]
2-element Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}:
 1
 2

julia> something.(output)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can force the `Int` type with `Int.(output)`. This is using Julia's broadcast syntax to apply the "constructor" of `Int` to all entries of the vector.

Comment: `something` in this case works, but in general it would unwrap `Some` if it were present in the array so it is not ideal. A general approach to automatic `eltype` narrowing AFAICT is to call `identity.(output)` or just `[v for v in output]`.

Comment: I think something will give an error if it sees `nothing` here. You can do `something.(output, 0)` to explicitly provide what it should give in such cases, if you prefer.

Comment: In the question it is explicitly stated that " it is known in advance that only values will be output". Hence the answer I gave.